# Home security alarm set off when breakers shut off!

Tags: security

I have a DSC Power 832 PC5010 security system in my home.  Although I have not armed the system since I purchased the house this past year, the alarm was set off recently when an electrician shut off all the electrical breakers prior to some work.  I was able to silence the alarm by unplugging the transformer in the closet.  I thought that the "dead" 12v battery was the reason why the alarm was triggered again when plugging the transformer back into outlet.  However, still triggers alarm even after installing new 12v battery.  I also noticed that the keypads are not functioning when the system is powered up via battery and/or transformer!

It's my understanding that the alarm is set off when breakers shut off as this has been a strategy for burglars in disengaging security systems in the past. However, I don't understand why the alarm is still set off after breakers switched back on!

Comment: I suspect that you'd have to enter a disarm code to get the alarm to shut off, but with keypads not working that's going to be difficult. I'm unclear what you're trying to accomplish: get the alarm system working again (even though you don't use it) or just prevent the alarm going off? If the latter, sounds like you can just leave it all unplugged; if the former, getting at least one keypad working is almost certainly essential to any further troubleshooting/fix.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard is locked by activating the protection for safety reasons.
Need to operate from the panel to stop the alarm.